# Evaluate model with lmfit

Tags: python, function, data-fitting, lmfit

I want to plot calculate and plot the predictions of my model out of the defined range of the input variables, and I am trying to do this with `lmfit`. Here is the code that I am working on. The model is defined as a function of just one independent variable `t`, but the function itself uses also another independent set of observations. I can calculate the new_times to which evaluate the model, but can not do the same for the other set of observations. Besides the terrible fit (not an issue per se here), I have highlighted the errors I get in case I use `lmfit` as I thought it worked:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from lmfit import Model
import scipy.integrate as it
import scipy.constants as scc

times=np.asarray([58418, 58422, 58424, 58426, 58428, 58430, 58540, 58542, 58650, 58654, 58656, 58658, 58660, 58662, 58664, 58666, 58668, 58670, 58672, 58674, 58768, 58770, 58772, 58774, 58776, 58778, 58780, 58782, 58784, 58786, 58788, 58790, 58792, 58794, 58883, 58884, 58886, 58888, 58890, 58890, 58892, 58894, 58896, 58898, 58904])

y_obs =np.asarray([ 0.00393986,0.00522288,0.00820794,0.01102782,0.00411525,0.00297762, 0.00463183,0.00602662,0.0114886, 0.00176694,0.01241464,0.01316199, 0.01108201, 0.01056611, 0.0107585, 0.00723887,0.0082614, 0.01239229, 0.00148118,0.00407329,0.00626722,0.01026926,0.01408419,0.02638901, 0.02284189, 0.02142943, 0.02274845, 0.01315814, 0.01155898, 0.00985705, 0.00476936,0.00130343,0.00350376,0.00463576, 0.00610933, 0.00286234, 0.00845177,0.00849791,0.0151215, 0.0151215, 0.00967625,0.00802465, 0.00291534, 0.00819779,0.00366089])

y_obs_err = np.asarray([6.12189334e-05, 6.07487598e-05, 4.66365096e-05, 4.48781264e-05, 5.55250430e-05, 6.18699105e-05, 6.35339947e-05, 6.21108524e-05, 5.55636135e-05, 7.66087180e-05, 4.34256323e-05, 3.61131000e-05, 3.30783270e-05, 2.41312040e-05, 2.85080015e-05, 2.96644612e-05, 4.58662869e-05, 5.19419065e-05, 6.00479888e-05, 6.62586953e-05, 3.64830945e-05, 2.58120956e-05, 1.83249104e-05, 1.59433858e-05, 1.33375408e-05, 1.29714326e-05, 1.26025166e-05, 1.47293107e-05, 2.17933175e-05, 2.21611713e-05, 2.42946630e-05, 3.61296843e-05, 4.23009806e-05, 7.23405476e-05, 5.59390368e-05, 4.68144974e-05, 3.44773949e-05, 2.32907036e-05, 2.23491451e-05, 2.23491451e-05, 2.92956472e-05, 3.28665479e-05, 4.41214301e-05, 4.88142073e-05, 7.19116984e-05])

p= np.asarray([ 2.82890497,3.75014266,5.89347542,7.91821558,2.95484056,2.13799544, 3.32575733,4.32724456,8.2490644, 1.26870083,8.91397925,9.45059128, 7.95712563, 7.58669608, 7.72483557,5.19766853,5.93186433,8.89793105, 1.06351782,2.92471065,4.49999613,7.37354766, 10.11275281, 18.94787684, 16.40097363, 15.38679306, 16.33387783, 9.44782842, 8.29959664,7.07757293, 3.42450524,0.93588962,2.515773,3.32857547,7.180216, 2.05522399, 6.06855409,6.1016838,10.8575614,10.8575614, 6.94775991,5.76187014, 2.09327787, 5.88619335,2.62859611])

def new_f_function(t, sum, f0, a, b, c, T0):

  obs_f = f0 + it.cumtrapz(-a * p**c + b, t-T0, initial=0)
  new_f = obs_f*(1+sum/scc.c)

  return new_f

# Create Model
model = Model(new_f_function, independent_vars=['t'])

# Initialize Parameter
params = model.make_params()

params['sum'].value = 1.483 
params['sum'].min = 1.47
params['sum'].max = 1.50

params['f0'].value = 1.483 
params['f0'].min = 1.47
params['f0'].max = 1.50

params['a'].value = 1.483 
params['a'].min = 1.47
params['a'].max = 1.50

params['b'].value = 1.483 

params['c'].value = 1.483 

params['T0'].value = 1.483 

result = model.fit(y_obs, params, weights=(1./y_obs_err), t=times, scale_covar=False)
print result.fit_report()

# New x-values to evaluate the model 
x_fit = np.linspace(min(times)-10., max(times)+10, 1e4)  

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(3, 6), sharex='all')
ax1.scatter(x=times, y=p, marker='+', c='k')
ax2.errorbar(x=times, y=y_obs, yerr=y_obs_err, marker='.', ls='', label='DATA')
ax2.plot(times, result.best_fit, label='best fit')

new_predictions = result.eval(**result.best_values)
#ax2.plot(x_fit, new_predictions, label='extended fit') # This gives error: `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10000,) and (45,)`

predicted = result.eval(t=x_fit) # This gives error: `raise ValueError("If given, length of x along axis must be the "ValueError: If given, length of x along axis must be the same as y.`

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is coming from `scipy.integrate.cumtrapz()`. Reading the full traceback would show you that.  The message is saying that the two arguments of `scipy.integrate.cumtrapz()` must be the same size.

Indeed, at `it.cumtrapz(-a * p**c + b, t-T0, initial=0)` the first argument will have a size set by your variable `p`, which is a fixed-length array and the second will be set by `t`, the independent variable of your model function.

So, when you do `result.eval(t=NEW_ARRAY)` you would definitely get that error message if your new array was not the same length as your array `p`.   That is the actual error. How would you solve it?  Well, you would have to somehow pass in an array for `p` that was the same length as the new `t` array.

It's generally a bad idea to mix global arrays and local arrays.  This illustrates one of the problems in doing so.  There are several other weird things going on that will make the fit not work very well.  Like a) why are all initial values the same, and b) why are you placing extremely tight (and the same) bounds on several of the parameters?  I guess those are not really the question here, but they are probably going to make the fit not work very well.

Comment: What is the best way to ignore the contribution of it.cumtrapz() at points where `p` is not defined: a newer definition of the function (such that the function includes that contribution only when `p` has no-zero values), or a newer `p` array with of the same size as `x_fit` but with `zeroes` where there are no actual data ?In any case, can you address me on how to implement the best solution?

Comment: What does "where p is not defined" mean?  It's an array.  It is supposed to correspond to another array?

Comment: I mean that `p` is the array of measurements at `times` (as well as `y_obs`). If I expand on the used times to evaluate a continuous function beyond the short range used to fit the model, I need to do an analogous thing with measured data.

Comment: I have no idea how you would extrapolate or interpolate your `p` array.  Maybe you want to interpolate/extrapolate the result instead of trying to evaluate it at points where you don't have all of the needed data.